# Stationarity in KKT condition

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I was learning the KKT conditions theory and in the notes the author was trying to prove the necessity of KKT conditions with bare hands. But I found a phenomenon which is a bit weird and I seek for some suggestions here.

---

Suppose $\hat{x}$ solves $$\min_{x\in \mathbb R^m} F(x) \quad\text{subject to } \quad G(x)\le 0\,,$$ where $F,G$ are from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R$, continuously differentiable.

Define $\mathcal{L}(x,\mu)=F(x)+\mu G(x)$, where $\mu\in \mathbb R$.

Consider the case that $G(\hat{x})<0$, i.e. $\hat{x} \in \{G(x)<0 \}$, which is open in $\mathbb R^m$.

Then $\nabla_x F(\hat{x})=0$. Recall that the stationarity condition in KKT is, there exists $\hat{\mu}$ such that $\nabla_x F(\hat{x})+\hat{\mu} \nabla_x G(\hat{x})=0$. Therefore we need to have that $\hat{\mu} \nabla_x G(\hat{x})=0$. If we choose $\hat{\mu}=0$, then we are done. But then $\mathcal{L}(x,\hat{\mu})$ reduces to $F(x)$.

It seems like introducing $\mathcal{L(x,\mathcal{\mu})}$ is somehow meaningless. What is the meaning of introducing KKT in this specific case? Thanks for posts and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you don't know before you find them, which, if any, of the minimizers $\ \hat{x}\ $ will satisfy the condition $\ G(\hat{x})<0\ $, and if $\ \hat{x}\ $ is a local minimizer for which $\ G(\hat{x})=0\ $, then it will *not* necessarily be true that $\ \nabla F(\hat{x})=0\ $.  Thus, if you want to be sure of finding *all* the minimizers, you will normally need to find *all* solutions of the *full* KKT conditions, which are
\begin{align}
\nabla F(\hat{x})+\hat{\mu}\nabla G(\hat{x})&=0\\
\hat{\mu}G(\hat{x})&=0\\
\hat{\mu}&\ge0
\end{align}
for this problem. Note that the last condition is also necessary.  If $\ \nabla F(\hat{x})+\hat{\mu}\nabla G(\hat{x})=0\ $, $\ \nabla F(\hat{x})\ne0\ $ and $\ \hat{\mu}<0\ $, then $\ \hat{x}\ $ cannot be a minimizer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something up. When you look for all $x$ such that $\nabla F(x)=0$, you are solving the problem $$\min_{x\in \mathbb R^m} F(x) \quad\text{subject to } \quad G(x)< 0.$$ This is usually regarded as an unconstrained minimization problem that does not need the use of the KKT conditions. So, in this specific case when you have an unconstrained minimization problem, the KKT conditions do not matter at all. It is important to emphasize that $$\min_{x\in \mathbb R^m} F(x) \quad\text{subject to } \quad G(x)\le 0$$ is a constrained minimization problem and not an unconstrained one. So, both problems are different problems and are treated differently. The constrained problem does need the KKT conditions, as discussed by Leggiera.